# Interface with Internal static class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Provider classes use different models, but I don't want to create a provider with same functionality for each model. **The c# I can use is 4.0 max**.

```
internal static class ProviderA
{
   internal static void GetData(Action<string> callback)
    {
       callback?.Invoke(DataA.GetData());
    }
}
    internal static class ProviderB
{
   internal static void GetData(Action<string> callback)
    {
       callback?.Invoke(DataB.GetData());
    }
}
```

Data Models:

```
public class DataA
{
    public string id;
    public string name;

    internal static string GetData()
    {
        //parsing data and returning some data value after parsing
        return someDataValue;
    }
    private static Helper()
    {
        // magic here. This class is used in parsing process in GetData method
    }
}
    public class DataB
{
    public string date;
    public string result;

    internal static string GetData()
    {
        //parsing data and returning some data value after parsing
        return someDataValue;
    }
    private static Eraser()
    {
        // magic here. This class is used in parsing process in GetData method
    }
}
```

How can I make code more generic, but with the same access modifiers to providers?

Comment: Is there a reason that your providers need to be static?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay okay, but if I change it to be non-static, what pattern should I use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use one of the foundational aspects of C# inheritance, polymorphism.  To be more generic, I believe you could leverage dependency injection and the factory pattern potentially if you can avoid the use of `static`.

```
public class IDataContext : IDisposable
{
     Task<TEntity> Get<TEntity>();    
     Task Delete();
}
```

The above code is our contract, no actual implementation logic.

```
public class DataContextA : IDataContext
{
     public async Task<string> Get<string>() => ...
     public async Task Delete() => ...
}

public class DataContextB : IDataContext
{
    public async Task<int> Get<int>() => ...
    public async Task Delete() => ...
}
```

The `...` implementation would simulate your actual implementation, for brevity I did not do any code.  I also left off the dispose implementation logic, that is also inherited via our interface contract.

```
public class DataContextFactory 
{
     IDataContext CreateContextA() => new DataContextA();
     IDataContext CreateContextB() => new DataContextB();
}
```

So now we have an easy way to implement the variations, so we would use in the following manner:

```
var factory = new DataContextFactory();
using DataContextA a = factory.CreateContextA();
var value = await a.Get();

using DataContextB b = factory.CreateContextB();
var value = await b.Get();

await a.Delete();
await b.Delete();
```

You can modify this approach further, but to know how beneficial would be up to you and your intent for your project.

An important note, you could be basic and not wrap in a factory and remove the dependency injection, but still leverage basic simpleton creation.

Answer (score 0):

The Adapter pattern is your friend if you can't modify the original providers to be non-static:

```
internal static class ProviderA
{
   internal static void GetData(Action<string> callback)
    {
       callback?.Invoke(DataA.GetData());
    }
}

internal static class ProviderB
{
   internal static void GetData(Action<string> callback)
    {
       callback?.Invoke(DataB.GetData());
    }
}

internal interface IProvider
{
    internal void GetData(Action<string> callback);
}

internal sealed class ProviderAWrapper : IProvider
{
    public void GetData(Action<string> callback)
    {
        ProviderA.GetData(callback);
    }
}

internal sealed class ProviderBWrapper : IProvider
{
    public void GetData(Action<string> callback)
    {
        ProviderB.GetData(callback);
    }
}
```

Then inject the interface into your data classes (constructor is typical) to use it.

**ETA:** You can even make a superclass of the adapters if there's shared functionality you want to centralize.

Comment: ok, and if I would make an instance and change original providers to be non-static, what pattern should I use then?

Comment: Just implement the interface directly. The example is a 1-to-1 adapter, so it's just removing a layer.